Django TestCase slef.client.patch gives a 404 error
I want to test the update function of a view set
from rest_framework.viewsets import ModelViewSet
@extend_schema(tags=['Customers'])
class CustomerViewSet(ModelViewSet):
    """ This view can be used to see all the customers"""
    serializer_class = CustomerSerializer
    .....
    def update(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        return self._update_customer(request, *args, **kwargs)

The route is mapped here (like the other view sets):
router.register(r'customers', CustomerViewSet, basename='customer')

Like for my other view sets where it works,
i test the update method by resolving it in my test case
from django.test import TestCase
from rest_framework.reverse import reverse
......
class CustomerUpdateViewTest(TestCase):
         .....
         def test_customer_missing(self):
             url = reverse('customer-detail', [2])        
             token = create_access_token(self.my_user)

             data = {
               'customer': 'new name customer'
             }

             response = self.client.patch(url, data, 
                content_type="application/json",
                HTTP_AUTHORIZATION=f'Bearer {token}')

I have created before in a setup method many customers
But the self.client.patch instruction give always a 404 error
In my running application,
the path is /api/customers/x (like in my test where x = a customer identifier)
and  is an HTTP PATCH verb
For my similar views, i test in a very similar way and it works.
When i give a wrong token, i have a 401 error, which indicate to my point of view that the url is correct.
Do you have already encountered such a problem ?
If yes, what can i do to solve this problem ?

Check what url is generated by reverse Does it look right? 401 status code is most likely raised by Middleware which is called before accessing any of the view code so url may still be incorrect

Thanks a lot Tomasz. The url seems to be good, i print it and it is identical to the observed url in the server.

The problem was the user with which I call the endpoint.
In the Django code (models) the user is of type:
from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractUser
class User(AbstractUser)

This user has the attribute is_superuser = False, but I called the endpoint with a user that is not super user. Calling the endpoint with a user that has the attribute is_superuser = True will succeed.
It was for me a little bit tricky because the 404 error is to my point of view not a true one. This 404 error hides a problem of authorization for a user that is not super user (or has not the permission to change the customer). I obtain the same error if I use in the reverse a pk value that does not exist for a customer. For example, as I use:
url = reverse('customer-detail', [2]) 

if I do not have a customer whose the pk value = 2, then I get a 404 error too.
Consequently, I use a super user to call the endpoint and also replace the existing reverse code by the following (with an existing pk for the customer):
url = reverse('customer-detail', [self.customer_to_test.pk])

